# Проблемы с оборудованием

Tags: linux, ubuntu, elementary-os

Чистая установка с обновлениями. Включал загрузку драйверов со всех источников. Нету звука не в динамиках не в наушниках. Нету как в ubuntu так и в elementary os. В ОС всё включено и ошибок нету. Какой-то фиктивный выход присутствует в настройках звука. Так же не определён микрофон и в приложении Камера нету возможности переключится на вторую переднюю. Так же есть проблемы с работой сенсерного экрана(Например, не могу прокрутить страницу в браузере, она выделяется только. Модель ноутбука `HP x2-10-p0005;` Можно что-нибудь из этого исправить? Есть ли где-нибудь мне нужные драйвера?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$ lspci -vnn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel
Corporation Device [8086:2280] (rev 36)     Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard
Company Device [103c:827c]  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Kernel driver in use: iosf_mbi_pci

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device
[8086:22b0] (rev 36) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])  DeviceName: 
Onboard IGD     Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:827c]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 311  Memory at
90000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]  Memory at 80000000
(64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]  I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>   Kernel driver in use: i915  Kernel
modules: i915

00:03.0 Multimedia controller [0480]: Intel Corporation Device
[8086:22b8] (rev 36)    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device
[103c:827c]     Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255     Memory at 91000000 (32-bit,
non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4M]  Capabilities: <access denied>

00:0a.0 Non-VGA unclassified device [0000]: Intel Corporation Device
[8086:22d8] (rev 36)    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device
[103c:827c]     Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255     Memory at 9193c000 (32-bit,
non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]  Capabilities: <access denied>

00:0b.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device
[8086:22dc] (rev 36)    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device
[103c:827c]     Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 312     Memory at 9193b000 (64-bit,
non-prefetchable) [size=4K]     Capabilities: <access denied>   Kernel
driver in use: proc_thermal     Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22b5]
(rev 36) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company
Device [103c:827c]  Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ
310     Memory at 91900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>   Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:1a.0 Encryption controller [1080]: Intel Corporation Device
[8086:2298] (rev 36)    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device
[103c:827c]     Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 313
    Memory at 91700000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]     Memory at
91600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]   Capabilities: <access
denied>     Kernel driver in use: mei_txe   Kernel modules: mei_txe

00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22c8] (rev
36) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])    Flags: bus master, fast devsel,
latency 0, IRQ 309  Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01,
sec-latency=0   Memory behind bridge: 91800000-918fffff     Capabilities:
<access denied>     Kernel driver in use: pcieport  Kernel modules:
shpchp

00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:229c] (rev
36)     Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:827c]   Flags: bus
master, medium devsel, latency 0    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich   Kernel modules: lpc_ich

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165
[8086:3165] (rev 81)    DeviceName: Intel Stone Peak I  Subsystem: Intel
Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:8010]   Flags: bus master, fast devsel,
latency 0, IRQ 314  Memory at 91800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable)
[size=8K]   Capabilities: <access denied>   Kernel driver in use:
iwlwifi     Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61657/discussion-on-question-by-aaa---).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Обновление ядра:

**1. Откройте терминал, скопируйте и выполните одну из команд, согласно архитектуры вашей системы: 32 или 64-bit.**

***Для 32-bit (одной командой):***

```
cd /tmp
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7/linux-headers-4.7.0-040700-generic_4.7.0-040700.201608021801_i386.deb
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7/linux-headers-4.7.0-040700_4.7.0-040700.201608021801_all.deb
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7/linux-image-4.7.0-040700-generic_4.7.0-040700.201608021801_i386.deb;
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

***Для 64-bit (одной командой):***

```
cd /tmp; wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7/linux-headers-4.7.0-040700-generic_4.7.0-040700.201608021801_amd64.deb
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7/linux-headers-4.7.0-040700_4.7.0-040700.201608021801_all.deb
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7/linux-image-4.7.0-040700-generic_4.7.0-040700.201608021801_amd64.deb;
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

**2. Обновите GRUB (GRUB надо обновлять в той системе Linux где он установлен, если у вас их более одной):**

```
sudo update-grub
```

**3. По окончании установки, закройте все приложения и перезагрузите компьютер следующей командой:**

```
sudo reboot
```

**4. После нового входа в систему, проверьте версию актуального ядра командой в терминале:**

```
uname -r
```

---

[Страница о мейнлайновых ядрах в вики Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds)

Comment: Это мне должно помочь? Просто я уже поставил Windows

Comment: мне с видюхой помогло, попробуйте, это не долго и не сложно

Comment: А при установке Linux и обновлении это автоматом не делается?

Comment: видимо нет, до обновления ядра, была другая версия,  не помню какая. линукс можно рядом поставить и проверить

Comment: Откуда эта информация?

Comment: полученная эмпирическим путем)

Comment: Если бы это 100% помогло бы, то стоило бы попробовать. Подскажите, можно сделать загрузочную флешку из микросд?

Comment: я думаю можно, но нужно microsd подключать через usb, т.к. не будет чтения при загрузке через кардридер, но я не уверен

Comment: Т е при обновлении ядра я перехожу на последнюю версию? Не LTS?

Comment: LTS  все та же, сама версия ядра другая

Comment: Как посмотреть ид устройств которые поддерживаются и имеются драйвера?

Comment: Команда lspci. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/lspci.8.html

Comment: [Страница о мейнлайновых ядрах в вики Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds) (возможно, стоит включить в ответ как источник).

Comment: Эту команды я вывел в вопросе. Что мне это дало? Драйверов то нету

Comment: https://losst.ru/dispetcher-ustrojstv-v-ubuntu

Comment: Не советовал бы запускать скрипты напрямую из сеть, пусть даже с офф сайта, на работе за такое бы уволили сразу. Вы уверены, что ноут не дефективный? Может не исправно железо. Попробуйте создайте загрузочную флешку с Fedora Linux (у них самые последнии обновления) и проверте есть ли звук когда грузитесь с нее. Если нету, несите мастеру.

Comment: @Hellseher Ноут не дефектный, в Окнах всё работает.

Answer (score 3):

**Диагностика**

Убедитесь, что железо действительно работает. Для этого, желательно, иметь загрузочные флешки с различными дистрибутивами (Fedora, Ubuntu, Arch). Если железо работает/работало раньше попробуйте следующее (буду показывать вывод от  своей машины):

Все команды выполняются из под root

Смотрим что у нас за BIOS:

```
~# dmidecode --type bios
# dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
        Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
        Version: P1.90
        Release Date: 03/04/2014
        Address: 0xF0000
        Runtime Size: 64 kB
        ROM Size: 8192 kB
        Characteristics:
                PCI is supported
                BIOS is upgradeable
                BIOS shadowing is allowed
                Boot from CD is supported
                Selectable boot is supported
                BIOS ROM is socketed
                EDD is supported
                5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
                8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
                Serial services are supported (int 14h)
                Printer services are supported (int 17h)
                ACPI is supported
                USB legacy is supported
                BIOS boot specification is supported
                Targeted content distribution is supported
                UEFI is supported
        BIOS Revision: 4.6
```

Ищем аудо устройсва, найденные системой:

```
~# lspci | grep -i audio
   00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

Ищем драйвер аудио устройства:

```
~# lspci -vnn | grep -A10 -i audio | grep -i modules
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Ищем драйвер аудио устройства в згруженных модулях:

```
~# grep snd_hda_intel /proc/modules
snd_hda_intel 36864 9 - Live 0xffffffffc05fc000
snd_hda_codec 126976 4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel, Live 0xffffffffc05dc000
snd_hda_core 81920 5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec, Live 0xffffffffc05b3000
snd_pcm 102400 5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core, Live 0xffffffffc0567000
snd 77824 27 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_pcm,snd_timer, Live 0xffffffffc03b4000
```

Ищем все комбинации аудо устройст в загруженных модулях:

```
~# lsmod | grep -i "aud\|snd\|sound"
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     45056  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek    90112  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          36864  9
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_seq                65536  0
snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_seq
snd_pcm               102400  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    77824  27 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

Из все этого следует, что ядро нашло аудо карту и загрузило драйвер. (Слушаю
музыку прямо сейчас)

**Исправление**

Если однxа из команд не показала вывода, проверям установленные аудо пакеты (на
Ubontu используйте dpkg-query -l):

```
~# rpm -qa | grep "alsa\|gstr"
wine-alsa-2.0-1.fc24.i686
gstreamer-plugins-base-0.10.36-15.fc24.x86_64
gstreamer1-libav-1.8.3-1.fc24.x86_64
gstreamer1-plugins-ugly-1.8.3-1.fc24.x86_64
alsa-utils-1.1.1-1.fc24.x86_64
gstreamer-plugins-good-0.10.31-17.fc24.x86_64
libnice-gstreamer1-0.1.13-4.fc24.x86_64
gstreamer-plugins-bad-free-0.10.23-34.fc24.x86_64
texlive-stringstrings-svn36203.1.23-24.fc24.1.noarch
gstreamer1-plugins-base-1.8.3-2.fc24.x86_64
gstreamer1-plugins-bad-free-1.8.3-3.fc24.x86_64
gstreamer1-plugins-base-1.8.3-2.fc24.i686
gstreamer-0.10.36-15.fc24.x86_64
gstreamer-ffmpeg-0.10.13-16.fc24.x86_64
gstreamer-plugins-bad-nonfree-0.10.23-3.fc24.x86_64
gstreamer-plugins-bad-0.10.23-7.fc24.x86_64
alsa-plugins-pulseaudio-1.1.1-1.fc24.x86_64
gstreamer1-1.8.3-1.fc24.x86_64
texlive-stringstrings-doc-svn36203.1.23-24.fc24.1.noarch
gstreamer-tools-0.10.36-15.fc24.x86_64
gstreamer1-1.8.3-1.fc24.i686
phonon-backend-gstreamer-4.9.0-1.fc24.x86_64
gstreamer1-plugins-bad-nonfree-1.8.3-1.fc24.x86_64
PackageKit-gstreamer-plugin-1.1.3-2.fc24.x86_64
alsa-lib-1.1.1-1.fc24.i686
phonon-qt5-backend-gstreamer-4.9.0-1.fc24.x86_64
gstreamer-plugins-ugly-0.10.19-19.fc24.x86_64
wine-alsa-2.0-1.fc24.x86_64
gstreamer1-plugins-good-1.8.3-2.fc24.x86_64
alsa-lib-1.1.1-1.fc24.x86_64
```

Comment: Я же Вам говорю, в Окнах все устройства работают.

Comment: dpkg-query -l |  grep "alsa\|gstr" Что выдает?